# How to store a segmented image as thematic image as opposed to continuous image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tiff

I have a result of image segmentation  image array as image(values as predicted class).when i save this image i get continuous layer type . But what i want is thematic layer type instead. 
What function or parameters i should use to save this image as thematic(in .tif format)
eg. a 3x3 image looks like

[2,3,1

0,1,2

3,1,2]

instead of pixel values like

[255,192,64

0,64,128

128,192,64]

I want histogram to read from 0-3. Instead histogram is in the range(0-256) for first 3x3 example image.
I am using tifffile  to write in .tif format

```
pred = numpy.argmax(ypreds, axis = 2)
tifffile.imwrite("pred1.tif", pred)
```

Comment: I have not heard of the term "thematic image" before. Could you maybe define it a bit more?

Comment: @trilarion for thematic type image, histogram has discreet values(eg. 0,1,2,3) instead of continuous range (0-255)

Comment: Do you want to say that a thematic image consists of only a few unique colors?

Comment: @Trilarion yes.It is a segmented image with only class labels/class colors in the metadata/histogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to save the values as you require:

```
import numpy as np
import tifffile

# Create representative image
y = np.random.randint(0,4,size=(3,3),dtype=np.uint8)

# Mine looks like this
# array([[1, 3, 3],
#        [0, 2, 3],
#        [1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

# Save as TIFF
tifffile.imsave("pred1.tif",y)
```

Now check contents with **ImageMagick** and values and histogram appear to match data:

```
magick identify -verbose pred1.tif 

Image: pred1.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 3x3+0+0
  Resolution: 1x1
  Print size: 3x3
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Type: Grayscale
  Endianess: LSB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Gray: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 9
    Gray:
      min: 0  (0)                              <--- matches image
      max: 3 (0.0117647)                       <--- matches image
      mean: 1.44444 (0.00566449)
      standard deviation: 1.33333 (0.00522876)
      kurtosis: -1.91725
      skewness: 0.105324
      entropy: 0.945531
  Colors: 4
  Histogram:                                   <--- matches image
         3: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
         2: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
         1: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 gray(2)
         3: (  3,  3,  3) #030303 gray(3)
```